# The name '..' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I just started out learning C# and I've run into a problem.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a text adventure! <press space to continue>");
            Console.ReadKey();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A monster aproaches what do you do? <Attack,Flee>");
                string a = Console.ReadLine();
            } while(a != "Attack" && a != "Flee"); 

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Im guessing its on the while line saying "a" doesnt exist - this is a matter of scope

Comment: `string a = Console.ReadLine();` placed inside `do` block, in a different scope than `while` beneath.

Comment: Just declare `string a` before the loop and you'll be fine

Comment: You seem to have edited the error message to remove vital information. I would be confident that it didn't say "The name '..' does not exist in the current context" but "The name 'a' does not exist in the current context". I am not sure why you chose to modify this information but all it does is makes it a little harder for people to immediately see where the error was. People did find it but the correct error message would undoubtedly have allowed them to do so faster.

Comment: I suggest checking only the first character of the user input - it will get tedious typing "Attack" and casing it correctly when all that is needed is "a".

Answer (score 3):

I think you should declare `a` as string variable outside the `do` block as this:

```
string a = "";

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("A monster aproaches what do you do? <Attack,Flee>");
    a = Console.ReadLine();
} while (a != "Attack" && a != "Flee");
```

The `while` tends to `Main` method scope, hence `a` must be exist on the `Main` before assigned inside `do` block.

Comment: There is no reason to assign a value to a on declaration since it is never going to be used. Neater and a little clearer (eg people might thing it matters what you initialize it to) in my opinion to just use `string a;`.

Answer (score 0):

hope error is 'a' variable, and fix is here....

'a' variable has to declare before the loop and you can assign value for 'a' inside of the loop for iteration

```
    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
      Console.WriteLine("This is a text adventure! <press space to continue>");
      string a ;
      do
       {
       Console.WriteLine("A monster aproaches what do you do? <Attack,Flee>");
       a = Console.ReadLine();
     } while(a != "Attack" && a != "Flee"); 

    }
    }
```

Comment: any explaination? Just dumping code doesn't help OP to understand the problem

Comment: @Toshi Done Tx.

Comment: Your second line of explanation is potentially a little confusing. The `a` variable was already accessible in the `do` so saying you need to do this to access it in the "do-while" is not quite accurate.

Comment: @chris Edited, Tx

Answer (score 0):

scope of 'a' was only till the closing bracket. declare it outside and than use.

```
 string a = "";
        Console.WriteLine("This is a text adventure! <press space to continue>");
        Console.ReadKey();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A monster aproaches what do you do? <Attack,Flee>");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (a != "Attack" && a != "Flee");
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do this  string a = ""; before setting the string with your readline and then you can use it like ur trying to do. Good luck! :)